# Publishing a web app listening on two different ports with TMG

Tags: microsoft-ftmg-2010

We have an internal web app built on some custom Java stuff. The app listens on port 8080, but also uses IIS on port 80 to get user authentication.

Opening the site in a browser produces HTTP GETs to both ports/urls.

Is a case like this possible to publish with TMG?

Comment: This should simply be a case of publishing both ports via the usual publishing routines for Forefront TMG. You'll need to create a second listener for one of the web apps/ports (and you may prefer to do that within a second firewall rule) but that should be about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, probably (sight unseen, but it's probably fiddleable to get it working).

Create two Web Publishing listeners, one for each port.

Create a rule which uses the first listener to publish the website, and check that much works.

If it does, (I think you can probably just) copy and paste that rule, then:

- change the listener over to the other one, and
- change the target publishing port over

And you should be good to go.